# Mongo server switch route to different DBs

Tags: mongodb

is there a possibility to configure mongo server so every time it accepts connection to certain database to route it to different database on same server.

Lets say for instance I have some spring-boot app, in my app I have declared params for mongo connection(Mongo server url, db name, credentials, etc.)

```
mongo.host=mongo.myhost.com
mongo.dbname=my-database
```

But on mongo server I have **my-database** , but I also have **new-database** (same collections, similar records) . Could I say somewhere in mongo server config that everytime a connection is requested to **my-database** to direct traffic to new-database? Or do I have to have some proxy server in between to route that kind of traffic.

Comment: This is not trivial because Spring expects the entire application to use the same database.  It begs the question, why?  Why do you need to interact with different databases?  Could you satisfy the same requirements in a more predictable way?

Comment: @barrypicker My spring app is using mongo just to read data. But every week I am having a whole new data release, done by data processing team which would make a whole new DB same in data structure , but with somewhat different data. Now all I want is that when they publish that I dont have to redeploy my spring app with new db in properties. But to use existing properties, and make a switch to new DB on mongo server side.

Comment: Understood.  This configuration change can be managed in a Spring configuration XML file.  But, when using the Spring XML config file, you only ever have one database reference in the application.  You would need to change the config file, then restart the app.  But, you don't need to redeploy the app.  By the way, the Spring XML configuration file can accept variables in the application.settings file.  This is how I generally prefer the setup - again to avoid a re-test and re-deploy.